# Ember.js Model is duplicated when going back. Using RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have got this route:

```
App.PanelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return this.store.find('topology');
}
});
```

With this view:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='panel'>

{{#each}}
  {{#link-to 'details' this}} Details{{/link-to}}
  {{name}}
  {{#each item in site}}
    {{item}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

This view shows 2 objects, but if I click the details link-to and then the back button, it calls the server again and return a duplicate of the model, then it renders 4 objects, the original 2 and a copy of them.
What's going on?

I am using RESTAdapter

```
App.Topology = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
site: DS.attr()
});
```

topologies:

```
{"topologies": [
{
"name": "name1",
"site": ["oneplace1","anotherplace1"]
},
{
"name": "name2",
"site": ["oneplace2","anotherplace2"]
}

]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ember / Ember Data are you using?

Apart from that you can try using `this.store.find('topology');`. `findAll` is a private method so you should not use it.

**Update**

It looks like your JSON response is lacking an `id` attribute for each record. Therefore Ember Data can't determine which records are already in the store.

Comment: Ember 1.5.0, Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.75ab8043, Using find instead of findAll gives me the same problem

Comment: @Pedro4441 see my updated answer. You are missing an `id` attribute in your JSON responses.

Comment: @stravid is correct, when the JSON returns items which have no id, ember-data cannot reconcile these with the items it already has in its cache. Each time you call store.find('topology') you will get 2 more records in your cache for 'topology'.